# Theming the background of an ActionBar

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm trying to simply change the background color of my app's ActionBar and am having a bit of trouble.

Here's my home screen layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_paper"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/impending_doom"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here are my styles:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTab</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/impending_doom</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTab">
        <item name="android:background">@color/impending_doom</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here's what the app looks like presently:

[image]

I'd like to simply change the background of the ActionBar. Why is what I'm doing already not working?

Comment: Are you using the regular ActionBar, the compatibility or ActionBarSherlock? What version of the API are you targeting?

Comment: The regular ActionBar, I think I'm targeting 11-14.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine. What is the value of `@color/impending_doom`?

Comment: In what files are those styles in? If you have a res/values-14/styles.xml then those will be used instead (or res/values-11/styles.xml).